# Electric Field Outside a Conductor and Dielectric

Tags: conductors, dielectric

I know that an electric field just outside of a conductor is E = local surface charge density / epsilon_0. If the surroundings of the conductor is a dielectric with permitivitty epsilon_1, does the electric field just outside the conductor become E = local surface charge density / epsilon_1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The General boundary conditions in Electrostatics given by
$$D^\perp_{above}-D^\perp_{below}=\sigma_f$$
$$\mathbf{D}^\parallel_{above}-\mathbf{D}^\parallel_{below}=\mathbf{P}^\parallel_{above}-\mathbf{P}^\parallel_{below}$$

where $\mathbf{D}$ is electric displacement given by
$$\mathbf{D}\equiv \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}$$

From here rest of follows. Note for linear media $$\mathbf{D}=\epsilon \mathbf{E}$$
As $\mathbf{P}=\epsilon_0\chi_0 \mathbf{E}.$

From here you yourself proceed.

Comment: Kindaicihi Thanks